# How to reset a Field Collection to its basic, unpopulated state via hook_form_alter()

Tags: entities

I am doing a form alter on a node edit form with a Field Collection which may have been previously populated.  I want to discard any previous data entered into the fields within the collection so it is in the same state as if the node were being newly created.

Thanks

Comment: Can you define 'previously populated'? Populated by whom/what/how?

Comment: Clive, previously populated simply means that someone has previously entered and submitted some content via the node form.

Comment: So it's a node edit page...?

Comment: Yes, or more accurately a node edit form.  To repeat the questions another way "How do I reset a field collection to its initial state ( ie. node just created ) from within a hook_form_alter() on the node edit form ?".

Comment: @elb - I think this is a good question. I ran into the same problem. I have a single embedded field collection on a node edit page. I would like to have a button that clears out the values in the field collection, returning it to its unpopulated state.

Comment: by rules, in my last action in rules, i just 'set a data value', the parent field colection to empty, and in worked